# How do I programmatically import a public key .cer file into a java keystore using JSSE?

Tags: java, jsse

I want to take a public key .cer file generated from java keytool command like this:

"keytool -export -alias privatekey -file publickey.cer -keystore privateKeys.store"

and import it into a new, empty java keystore like this:

"keytool -import -alias publiccert -file publickey.cer -keystore publicCerts.store"

except I want to do the import programmatically, using JSSE.

Stack Overlords, work your magic! Thanks!

Comment: JSSE may not be the right acronym. JCE perhaps? Whatever the Java API that deals with keystores is called! :)

Comment: Thanks guys. I would upvote you but I don't have enough credit to do so yet. Following Reginaldo's advice, I figured it out after looking at the decompiled KeyTool source. I did something similar to this: 

Certificate cert = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509").generateCertificate(new FileInputStream(certFileLocation));
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("publickey", cert);

Answer (score 2):

Look at the KeyStore class in Java. [Here](http://traser.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/traser/0.3/TraSer/src/net/sf/traser/common/KeystoreManager.java?view=markup) is a class which might give you some hints. You might require the free [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) crypto provider to operate all of its function

Answer (score 0):

If you use [jad](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad) to decompile the tools.jar that comes with Sun JDK, you will see exactly how it works.

Unzip the tools.jar in a folder and use the following command to decompile all classes
inside that jar.

```
for i in $(find . -name "*.class" | perl -ple 's/\.class$//g'); do jad -p $i.class > $i.java; done
```

The keytool source can be seen in class sun.security.tools.KeyTool